# Extracting href from beautifulsoup: why None?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing a site using BeautifulSoup4.  The code:

```
for link in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "fl nav_left_2j"}):
    for item in link.find_all("li"):
        print(item)
```

Gets me:

```
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince1.htm" title="点击查看 北京市 更多领导信息">北京市</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince18.htm" title="点击查看 天津市 更多领导信息">天津市</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince35.htm" title="点击查看 河北省 更多领导信息">河北省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince219.htm" title="点击查看 山西省 更多领导信息">山西省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince351.htm" title="点击查看 内蒙古自治区 更多领导信息">内蒙古自治区</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince465.htm" title="点击查看 辽宁省 更多领导信息">辽宁省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince580.htm" title="点击查看 吉林省 更多领导信息">吉林省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince650.htm" title="点击查看 黑龙江省 更多领导信息">黑龙江省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince792.htm" title="点击查看 上海市 更多领导信息">上海市</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince810.htm" title="点击查看 江苏省 更多领导信息">江苏省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince926.htm" title="点击查看 浙江省 更多领导信息">浙江省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince1028.htm" title="点击查看 安徽省 更多领导信息">安徽省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince1150.htm" title="点击查看 福建省 更多领导信息">福建省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince1245.htm" title="点击查看 江西省 更多领导信息">江西省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince1357.htm" title="点击查看 山东省 更多领导信息">山东省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince1515.htm" title="点击查看 河南省 更多领导信息">河南省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince1692.htm" title="点击查看 湖北省 更多领导信息">湖北省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince1809.htm" title="点击查看 湖南省 更多领导信息">湖南省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince1946.htm" title="点击查看 广东省 更多领导信息">广东省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince2089.htm" title="点击查看 广西壮族自治区 更多领导信息">广西壮族自治区</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince2213.htm" title="点击查看 海南省 更多领导信息">海南省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince2240.htm" title="点击查看 重庆市 更多领导信息">重庆市</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince2279.htm" title="点击查看 四川省 更多领导信息">四川省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince2482.htm" title="点击查看 贵州省 更多领导信息">贵州省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince2580.htm" title="点击查看 云南省 更多领导信息">云南省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince2726.htm" title="点击查看 西藏自治区 更多领导信息">西藏自治区</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince2807.htm" title="点击查看 陕西省 更多领导信息">陕西省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince2925.htm" title="点击查看 甘肃省 更多领导信息">甘肃省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince3026.htm" title="点击查看 青海省 更多领导信息">青海省</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince3078.htm" title="点击查看 宁夏回族自治区 更多领导信息">宁夏回族自治区</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince3106.htm" title="点击查看 新疆维吾尔自治区 更多领导信息">新疆维吾尔自治区</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince3220.htm" title="点击查看 香港特别行政区 更多领导信息">香港特别行政区</a></li>
*****
<li><a href="/web/20171221213907/http://ldzl.people.com.cn:80/dfzlk/front/personProvince3221.htm" title="点击查看 澳门特别行政区 更多领导信息">澳门特别行政区</a></li>
*****
<li><a>台湾省</a></li>
*****
```

Which is great!

Now I want to extract the href (and eventually the title, but I'm assuming if I solve for one I solve for both).  According to the docs, I should be able to add:

```
print(item.get('href'))
```

and get all of the links.  Unfortunately, all I get is "None".  But there are hrefs there!  I can see them!  I'd prefer not to have to build a bunch of regexes if there is built in functionality to do this correctly.  What mindbogglingly obvious thing am I doing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: Try `item[0].get('href')` (`<li>` themselves have no `href` in your data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `item` there is `<li>` stored. You have to extract `<a>` first. You can do it by sth like: `item.find('a').get('href')`.

Comment: Thank you!  I now feel less crazy.

Answer (score 0):

```
for link in item.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this because getting the item from find_all will only return data with tags and moreover for extracting links, one needs to find `<a>` tag directly in `div` and extract `href`

```
for item in link.find_all("li"):
    print(item.a["href"])
```

Comment: This throws error when `href` is not present into a tag

Comment: Yes that's one of the very rarest case because as far as I know it is not even safe to use `anchor tag` (`<a>`) without `href`. So mostly `href` exists, may be empty but it would be there.

Comment: Actually, an `<a>` without `href` is fairly common to *define* link targets: `<a name="..."/>`.

Comment: Please provide more details on why this code works. What is the rationale of your approach? Why does it work where the OP's approach failed?